# Jmeter: Parsing JSON responses in BeanShell Prepocessor and store it in a variable

Tags: json, jmeter, beanshell

Jmeter: How to extract & store the accountID in a variable from response using BeanShell preprocessor ? Can we use JSON or regular expression for this.

**My Response some what look like:**

```
    {
   "address":{
      "street1":"6550 Vallejo Street",
      "street2":"",
      "city":"Emeryville",
      "state":"CA",
      "zipcode":"98456",
      "country":"Uk"
   },
   "timezone":"US/Pacific-New",
   "reference":"fe_qa001",
   "token":"ns7h4rqVZegSZG6yZls6",
   "login":"fe_qa001@qa.com",
   "accountId":-9223372036762408565,
   "firstName":"qa029",
   "lastName":"svcqa",
   "email":"fe_qa001@qa.com",
   "component":[
      {
         "type":1,
         "reference":"12-1",
         "version":"1",
         "base":"Plastic",
         "zipcode":"94556",
         "bedsize":"high",
         "bed":false,
         "componentId":0,
         "code":"P5",
         "sku":"abcd",
         "serial":"1234",
         "purchaseDate":1372723200000,
         "chamber":2
      }
   ]
}
```

I am a newbie to Jmeter. So can anyone help me here. The requirement is like exacting the account ID from the response given below and store it in a variable using BeanShell Preprocessor.

Comment: I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
JsonObject accountId = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString);
JsonArray accountId = accountId.get(1).asObject().get("accountId").asString();
vars.put("accountId_BSH",accountId);

Answer (score 6):

I don't know where did you get this code, but it looks like it is using [minimal-json](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json/tree/master/com.eclipsesource.json/src/main/java/com/eclipsesource/json) library and uses it in a weird way, so

1. Make sure minimal-json.jar is in JMeter classpath
2. You have restarted JMeter to pick the .jar up
3. You have all the necessary imports

Also your code doesn't seem to work properly with the minimal-json-0.9.4.jar, you should modify it as:

```
import com.eclipsesource.json.JsonObject;

String jsonString = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); 
JsonObject accountId = JsonObject.readFrom(jsonString);
vars.put("accountId_BSH",String.valueOf(accountId.getLong("accountId",0L)));
```

---

You can do the same easier using [JSR223 PostProcessor and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance). Groovy has built-in JSON support so you won't have to add any .jars. Reference Groovy code:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper();
def response = jsonSlurper.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
vars.put("accountId_BSH", response.accountId.toString());
```

---

And probably the best way is using [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) available since [JMeter 3.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-key-things-you-need-know-about-jmeter-30). The relevant configuration will be something like:

- Variable Names: `accountId_BSH`
- JSON Path Expressions: `$.accountId`

[image: JSON Path Post]